# Why is FORTRAN recommended for astrodynamics rather than MATLAB?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design, simulation, astrodynamics, celestial-mechanics

I understand that FORTRAN might be faster in terms of computation time, but I don't understand why it is always recommended by people in the field. Everyone tends to avoid MATLAB for astrodynamics; is there a solid reason behind this, or is it just the preference of the majority?

MATLAB offers a lot of features not found in FORTRAN (such as visualizations or linking with other software).

Comment: Can you give some examples of these recommendations?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I meant that people doing astrodynamics and astrophysics always recommend using FORTRAN. Examples can be solving the CR3BP or Orbital Trajectories.

Comment: Isn’t the recommendation “use a validated code”, many of which happen to be written in FORTRAN because they’re old and experienced?

Comment: @BobJacobsen not really, I have been recommended multiple times to write the code myself in FORTRAN without any reference for validation. I always get the sense that i'd be doing a big mistake if I chose MATLAB to write the codes. But you are right, they usually have been using FORTRAN from ages.

Comment: I've used Matlab in the past and of course it works well; people keep shelling out money for it. But if I understand correctly, it's a black box; you don't always know how all the tools are working or what impacts their speed or what bugs they might have or whatever. I don't use it any more so I'm not qualified to write an answer. FORTRAN is the language of the gods (unless you're Brian of Nazareth, in which case it's that language that begins with "P") Seriously, it's a good language and its still used because it's absolutely well understood for numerical work, oh, and compiled and fast!

Comment: Who know, even parts of Matlab *might be* written in FORTRAN (libraries, etc.) and that's the point, we won't know because Matlab is a black box. There, I've gone and answered a question I'm not qualified to answer.

Comment: @uhoh ah this makes sense, basically FORTRAN is used because its a lower level of programming. I am currently "literally right now" writing some code for orbital analysis and I decided to write the libraries both in MATLAB and FORTRAN since I am still convinced with MATLAB but the astrodynamic society does FORTRAN only :)

Comment: This comment thread makes me happy since my simulation engineering years were using FORTRAN. I chuckled at the 'lower level' comment, remembering assembly language routines!

Comment: MatLab probably uses a stack. tricky blighters, stacks.

Comment: "Everyone tends to avoid MATLAB for astrodynamics". This is not true - lots of new astrodynamics work being published these days is prototyped using Matlab. Matlab becomes problematic when moving beyond prototyping for many reasons, though, which is why you rarely encounter full astrodynamics libraries written in Matlab.

Comment: @Adham I don't know if "low level" is exactly correct, or even the right way to look at it. FORTRAN is *compiled* and *open source* which I loosely associate with "can be used to write numerical calculations that can run fast" and "not a black box". See [Why is fortran extensively used in scientific computing and not any other language?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_fortran_extensively_used_in_scientific_computing_and_not_any_other_language) (34 answers!) and [Why physicists still use Fortran](http://moreisdifferent.com/2015/07/16/why-physicsts-still-use-fortran/)

Comment: and [Scientific computing’s future: Can any coding language top a 1950s behemoth?](https://arstechnica.com/science/2014/05/scientific-computings-future-can-any-coding-language-top-a-1950s-behemoth/) The last two contain the quote *“I don't know what the language of the year 2000 will look like, but I know it will be called Fortran.” —Tony Hoare, winner of the 1980 Turing Award, in 1982.*

Comment: @Chris Could you write up some of those many reasons as an answer?

Comment: I can't answer specifically on FORTRAN except for the use of legacy code (which is already mentioned in the comments) but I personally use C for my astrodynamics applications. Numerical integration is a pretty intensive task and C or FORTRAN are much better at performing it quickly than MatLab. I've previously linked an atmospheric model (JB2008) written in FORTRAN to my propagator in C because there was no implementation of it in C already. 
Write your core in FORTRAN or C and use MEX to call it from MatLab and process your results there. Nobody wants to plot anything from FORTRAN or C.

Comment: @AlexanderVandenberghe indeed. Most of the numerical routines in Python's SciPy https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10121 are the same thoroughly vetted and documented FORTRAN routines that most people start with, and calling your own routines (FORTRAN or C) from Python is (apparently) straightforward. Plotting is not as easy as in Matlab, but oh well.

Comment: Calculating using FORTRAN and visualizing with MATLAB should be possible and easy.

Comment: @Schwern I think an answer centered on "why Matlab is bad" would be mostly off-topic here, but see my answer below (and in particular, the link).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As many of the comments have already mentioned, there are several different reasons people might recommend the use of Fortran over Matlab. One of the most straightforward answers is that **a lot of legacy (read: validated) code is written in Fortran**, and depending on your job function, learning to use Fortran might make you more productive - for instance, if you have to use, maintain, and extend these tools.

Another reason (also mentioned in the comments) is, basically, **performance**. Well-written Fortran code is about as performant as you're going to get, and Fortran has the added benefit of being a farily straightforward language in which to write scientific code. Solving differential equations is computationally intensive, and since that is a core task of most astrodynamics code (orbit propagation), it makes sense to stick with a language that can give you good performance. Modern astrodynamics work often requires solving these differential equations many times over (e.g. for Monte Carlo simulations or optimization tasks), making performance even more critical. Of course, one could write performance-critical code in Fortran or C and link to the libraries in Matlab, but often it's easier to be consistent and stay in a single environment, particularly for students with limited time to learn multiple languages (although this is mostly a matter of preference).

Finally, **[Matlab has several design flaws](https://www.rath.org/matlab-is-a-terrible-programming-language.html) (which I won't elaborate on here) that make it a poor choice for implementing a large, complex codebase** (although, of course, many large codebases have been written in Matlab). Astrodynamics code in particular has a tendency to get complicated quickly for even basic tasks - for example, you may want to "just" propagate an orbit, so you need a flexible ODE solver, but you also need to simulate various perturbations, handle reference frame transformations and different time systems, etc. A flexible astrodynamics codebase can be sprawling, and I know from experience that it gets extremely messy in Matlab. Fortran is well-suited to this type of code. It's worth noting that it's not *required* to use Fortran for performant, well-structured codebases - [the Julia language](https://julialang.org/) is one example of a "high-level" language that does not have the deficiencies of Matlab.

Comment: Good answer -- I want to point out though, that people should not take away from this that Fortran is intrinsically faster than any other compiled language.  In fact, the Gnu compiler suite convert Fortran and C to the same intermediate language before compiling, and the Gnu Fortran runtime is written in C.  Institutional momentum, not wanting to reinvent the wheel, and reuse of validated code are the biggest reasons.  That Fortran is not slower than alternatives, and that it has a defined interoperability standard with C, helps maintain its status.